# Parent jquery/javascript affecting document also

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So, I have some jquery/javascript that is executing in an HTML page, and is supposed to check whether the parent page iframe has an id attribute, and if not to add one.

However, the below code seems to add the id to all iframes in the current page where the code is executing as well, not just the parent one.

Where oh where am I going wrong?

```
if($('iframe#iframe1', window.parent.document).length == 0)
   {
   console.log('no iframe id');
   $('iframe', window.parent.document).attr('id','iframe1');
   console.log('iframe id added');
   }
```

Comment: You can directly access the containing iframe element using [`window.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement) as long as both iframe and parent are same origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is working correctly you should use a combination selector to target the iframe you need

```
if($('iframe#iframe1', window.parent.document).length == 0)
   {
   console.log('no iframe id');
   $('.classcontainername iframe', window.parent.document).eq(0).attr('id','iframe1');
   console.log('iframe id added');
   }
```

you also use the .eq(0) to limit to the first instance